# Como estender a capacidade de armazenamento de variáveis char

Tags: c

olá! estou tendo problemas com um "mini dicionario" que estou montando.... ele está basicamente pronto, porém a definição das palavras, por serem longas demais, apresentam um erro ao serem exibidas. Suponho eu que seja por causa de alguma limitação do tipo de variável usado. Se alguém puder me ajudar eu ficarei agradecido.
Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct dicionario {

    char palavra[21];
    char definicao[51];

};

bool compararpalavras (const char palavra1[], const char palavra2[]) {

    int x = 0;

    while (palavra1[x] == palavra2[x] && palavra1[x] != '\0' && palavra2[x] !='\0') {

        ++x;

}
    if (palavra1[x] == '\0' && palavra2[x] == '\0') {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }
}

int procurarpalavras (const struct dicionario lingua[], const char palavra[], const int numdepalavras) {


    bool compararpalavras (const char palavra1[], const char palavra2[]);

    int x = 0;

    while (x < numdepalavras) {

        if (compararpalavras( lingua[x].palavra, palavra)) {

            return x;

        } else {

             ++x;

        }       
    }
    return -1;  
}

int main (void) {

    int procurarpalavras (const struct dicionario lingua[], const char palavra[], const int numdepalavras);

    const int NUMERODEDEFINICOES = 7;
    char palavra[21] = {'\0'};
    int resultadopesquisa;
    int sair;

    const struct dicionario portugues[7] = {
    {"C", "Linguagem de programacao considerada de baixo nivel"},
    {"cafe", "Combustivel usado por programadores"}, 
    {"java", "Linguagem de programacao avancada"},
    {"computador", "dispositivo provido de hardware e software capaz de executar operacoes matematicas de alto nivel"},
    {"windows", "Sistema operacional amplamente utilizado por pessoas desprovidas de conhecimentos avancados na area de computacao"},
    {"mac", "Sistema operacional criado por Steve Jobs, o proprietario da empresa de tecnologia aplle"},
    {"pizza", "tipico aperitivo consumido por programadores durante turnos estendidos"}};

    printf("*==================================================================*\n");
   printf("|                      DICIONARIO GEEK V. 1.0                      |\n");
   printf("|                                                                  |\n");
   printf("|Autor: Luis Paulo T. Franca                                       |\n");
   printf("*==================================================================*\n\n");

    printf ("digite uma palavra: ");
    scanf ("%s", palavra);

    resultadopesquisa = procurarpalavras (portugues, palavra, NUMERODEDEFINICOES);

    if (resultadopesquisa != -1) {
        printf ("%s\n", portugues[resultadopesquisa].definicao);
    } else {
        printf ("\npalavra nao encontrada\n");
    }
    system ("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está usando a seguinte declaração:

```
struct dicionario {
    char palavra[21];
    char definicao[51];
};
```

As definições de seus verbetes não podem ter mais que 50 caracteres. Agora vamos contar... A definição que você deu para o Windows tem 113. Se considerarmos o caractere nulo para terminação, temos 114.

Você tem duas opções. A bruta é simplesmente aumentar o tamanho das definições de acordo.

A elegante é usar ponteiros ;) i.e.:

```
struct dicionario {
    char* palavra;
    char* definicao;
};
```

Você continua construindo os structs do mesmo jeito. A "mágica" aqui é que um ponteiro apenas aponta para um endereço na memória - no caso, um ponteiro para uma palavra aponta para o primeiro caractere. Ao usar um acessor de índice, você está dizendo para o programa acessar um endereço na memória mais pra frente e ver o que tem lá. Ou seja:

```
palavra[0];
```

... Pega o que estiver no endereço inicial, mas:

```
palavra[5];
```

... Pega o que estiver (tamanho de um char na memória X cinco) bytes depois do endereço do caractere inicial. Para todos os efeitos, isso pega o sexto caractere.

Pode ser necessário fazer um ajuste ou outro no código - seria interessante aprender as funções de alocação (pesquise por `alloc`, `malloc`, `calloc` e `free`), por exemplo. Quaisquer problemas, faça mais perguntas aqui ;)

P.S.: Trabalhar com ponteiros requer um pouco de cuidado e exige alguma dedicação para aprender. Mas se você vai trabalhar com C, ou se pretende seguir adiante com isso além de um trabalho de faculdade, então não tem jeito. Ou você aprende, ou muda de tecnologia.

P.P.S.: ao pesquisar para responder a esta pergunta, descobri que buscar no Google por `c strings` é altamente NSFW. Não busquem por isso no trabalho ou na faculdade.